# Compress in .tgz

Tags: bash, compression, tar, gzip

I want to compress files in .tgz. I know how to make tar.gz(with tar and gzip) and some people say it is almost the same, but I need to make a .tgz, how??

Answer (score 113):

A tar.gz file and a .tgz file are similar.

**Compress** files using tar:

```
tar -cvzf <name of tarball>.tgz /path/to/source/folder
```

for example, I want to create a `backup.tgz` or `backup.tar.gz` from folder `/home/user/project`

```
tar -cvzf backup.tgz /home/user/project

tar -cvzf backup.tar.gz /home/user/project
```

You can use `tar cvzf` instead of `tar -cvzf` as well.

**Extract** .tgz or .tar.gz files using tar

```
tar -xvzf backup.tgz

tar -xvzf backup.tar.gz
```

---

Mnemonic for **compression** *(the order of the flags do not matter)*

- **C** ompress
- **Z** ee
- **F** ile
- **V** erbose

Mnemonic for **extraction** *(the order of the flags do not matter)*

- e **X** tract
- **Z** ee
- **F** ile
- **V** erbose

Comment: Is there a flag to have a password when you compress your file?

Comment: Nitpick: the order of the flags does matter for **f**: it must be the last flag, otherwise it fails.

Comment: For the flags, **`c`** is better remembered as create, and **`z`** is remembered as compression, as in the `z` from **z**lib, g**z**ip, **z**ip.  A better mnemonic would be **C** reate **Z** ipped **F** ile.

Comment: Aren't `.tar.gz` file and a `.tgz`  *exactly* the same?

Comment: @ImmanuelWeihnachten these are just file extensions without any explicit meaning. You give meaning to them. And yes, `.tar.gz` and a `.tgz` considered the same.

Answer (score 14):

It's the same. Just rename the file from `file.tar.gz` to `file.tgz`.

Comment: You've forgotten the command for renaming a file: `mv file.tar.gz file.tgz`. Obvious, but worth mentioning